# (Simple)DateFormat that allow 24:00:00 and 00:00:00 as inputs

Tags: java, jodatime, simpledateformat, java-time

I've been looking for this for a while, with no success so far. Do you know if there's a "DateFormat" ish class, that will allow me to use "00:00:00" and "24:00:00" as input parameters (they're both midnight) but when called "getHour()" I'll get 0 or 24 as a result?

Using "kk" will only allow me to have <1:24> range, meanwhile I'm looking for <0:24> range formatting

Comment: The <0:24> format doesn't make any sense. Or if it does, it might as well be <0:25>, or <0:26>, or <0:29293>, etc, because they all roll over the 24 hour limit so are all equally 'legal'. In a 24 hour clock format, the first minute is 00:00, and the last minute is 23:59. The minute after 23:59 is 00:00 again. 24:00 doesn't exist

Comment: @deyur your thinking of hh in which the hours are 1-23, the hours in kk are 1-24.

Comment: @UnknownOctopus I am thinking of hh because OP wants the hour to begin at 0. I agree with you that kk hours are 1-24 but that still doesn't make 0-24 legal (in any format).

Comment: @deyur Oh, ok, now i see, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @deyur 24:00 makes sense, see ISO-8601-paper where it is explicitly allowed and described as midnight at the end of the day.

Comment: @deyur Another example from real world: One of my super-markets around the corner shows the shop opening time in letters "7 - 24". Do you still pretend that this time does not exist? But indeed, in contrast to 24:00 I have not yet seen opening times like 25 etc.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Fair enough, I did not realise that this was legal under ISO-8601. I was incorrect. That said, I disagree with the supermarket example of "7-24" because that only applies here if the supermarket would also say something like "0-24" which I have never seen. To reiterate I do not think that 24 as an hour never exists, just that it is unusual to say that both 0 and 24 can both be legal in the single format. I don't think there are many real-world examples where you would see both. But you are right, ISO-8601 allows it.

Answer (score 11):

The value `24:00` is not represented in a `LocalTime` because it is strictly part of the next day. Consideration was given to models where `24:00` could be represented as part of `LocalTime`, but the conclusion was that it would be very confusing in a lot of use cases, and create more bugs than it solves.

---

There is support for `24:00` in `java.time` however. It is perfectly possible to parse it using the standard formatting techniques, however it is necessary to use SMART or LENIENT mode, see [ResolverStyle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html). The default mode is SMART, however the formtter constants on `DateTimeFormatter` like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` are in STRICT mode. Thus, `ofPattern()` defaults to SMART mode:

```
static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2012-12-03T24:00", FORMATTER);
System.out.println(ldt);  // 2012-12-04T00:00
```

Note that this also works for `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`. The standard parser for `Instant` supports `24:00` without a special formatter:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2015-01-01T24:00:00Z");
System.out.println(instant);  // 2015-01-02T00:00:00Z
```

Any formatter can be converted to SMART or LENIENT mode using [withResolverStyle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-) as follows:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = ...  // obtain a formatter somehow
DateTimeFormatter smartMode = f.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.SMART);

// for example
f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.SMART);
```

---

The second element of support is [parseExcessDays()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedExcessDays--). This allows the excess day to be obtained when only the time is being parsed:

```
static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

TemporalAccessor parsed = TIME_FORMATTER.parse("24:00");
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.from(parsed);
Period excessDays = parsed.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedExcessDays());
System.out.println(lt + " + " + excessDays);  // 00:00 + P1D
```

---

Finally, a note for advanced users. It should in theory be possible to write your own implementation of `Temporal` that is a copy of `LocalTime` but with support for `24:00` as a valid value. Such a class, say `LocalTimeWithEndOfDay`, could then operate with the formatter/parser without issue (and might make a good addition to [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/).

Comment: Well, I think the real problem of OP is not about leniency (smart, strict etc., see also `SimpleDateFormat` in lenient mode) but about how to achieve the feature `getHour() == 24` on the parsed result if the input is "24:00:00". So the only element of support in Java-8 is limited to `parseExcessDays()` (and the abstract option to implement a new `Temporal`-class). Do you agree?

Answer (score 9):

First let's make clear that the time **24:00 is a valid ISO-8601-time**. Citation from ISO-8601:

```
4.2 Time of day
4.2.1 General
  This International Standard is based on the 24-hour timekeeping System
  that is now in common use. In expressions of time of day
  hour is represented by two digits from [00] to [24]. The representation
  of the hour by [24] is only allowed to indicate the end of a calendar
  day, see 4.2.3.
```

Java itself does not support 24:00 unless you use the **lenient parsing mode of `SimpleDateFormat`**. But even then the support is not available because if you ask the result (an instance of `java.util.Date`) for the hour you get zero as you have already observed. Similar thoughts are valid for `java.util.GregorianCalendar`. After parsing, there is no chance to determine if the input was 24:00 or not (without knowing what the original input was).

**Java-8** also has no real support for this special hour. The best thing you can do here is using [parseExcessDays()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedExcessDays--) applied on the raw parsed data of `DateTimeFormatter`. You could use a workaround like this:

```
String input = "24:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
TemporalAccessor raw = dtf.parse(input);
int hour = raw.query(LocalTime::from).getHour();
Period period = raw.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedExcessDays());
if (period.equals(Period.ofDays(1))) {
  hour = 24;
}
System.out.println("iso-hour=" + hour); // output: iso-hour=24
```

The popular 3rd-party library **Joda-Time** has no support for 24:00. The situation is similar to `SimpleDateFormat`.

The only library with built-in support I am aware of is [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) which I have written myself. The full support is limited to `PlainTime` (similar pendant to `LocalTime`), not valid for complete date-time-representations (where it would be ambivalent, timestamps containing 24:00 will automatically be normalized to next day at 00:00):

```
PlainTime time = Iso8601Format.EXTENDED_WALL_TIME.parse("24:00:00");
System.out.println(time.get(PlainTime.ISO_HOUR)); // 24
```

Note that the state space of class `PlainTime` is slightly extended such that it can hold this special ISO-time-value. Therefore a direct programmatical access like this is possible:

```
PlainTime time24 = PlainTime.midnightAtEndOfDay(); // or: PlainTime.of(24, 0);
System.out.println(time24); // T24
```

Comment: Probably I will consider the introduction of [a new pattern type for the next release of Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/issues/314) based on CLDR with the deviation H=iso-hour in range 0-24.