# Set 24:00 as java time

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to map "24:00:00" as time to a model and then using model to save data in postgres DB.

The problem is whenever I'm trying to set "24:00:00" as value to any of **java.util.Date**, **java.sql.Time** or **java.time.LocalTime** the value is getting adjusted to "00:00:00" before saving "24:00:00" to DB as these datatypes only support hours in the range of "*0-23*".

I'm not able to figure out how to achieve this, I tried looking at the similar questions but to no avail. Any suggestions how can I manage to map "24:00:00"?

Comment: That's like asking how to save the number 1.200 in the database, and complaining it's "adjusted" to 1.2. 1.2 and 1.200 are the same number. It's just formatted in a different way. So save the Date you want in the database, without thinking about its representation, but by thinking of its value. Then, when displaying that date, display it the way you want to.

Comment: okay so you are suggesting , whenever I'm extracting that value from DB it should be explicitly set to "24:00:00". okay got it. But is there any way to save "24:00:00" as time to model only.

Comment: It’s a design decision that `LocalTime` only goes up to 23:59:59.999999999. In some cases, like yours, 24:00 would have made sense, in others not. Does your database column support a value of 24:00? Which DBMS and datatype are you using?

Comment: @OleV.V.yes postgres supports 24:00:00, using time datatype "time without time zone". I'm facing problem with java side.

Comment: There is always _some_ difference between the last time of one day and the first time of the next day. So if you don't want to lose any time, the end time of the first day has to be equal to the start time of the second day.

Comment: @SapuSeven yes that is correct, but I'm not considering days. It would have been much simpler to achieve with the inclusion of days.

Comment: Possible (near?) duplicate of [How to store time greater than 24 Hours in Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915200/how-to-store-time-greater-than-24-hours-in-mysql).

Comment: I am not aware of any database which supports 24:00 notation (as midnight at  end of day), but you could of course store it as number of let's say seconds or milliseconds (depending on your precision needs). And if you want to map it to a value object in Java then you either construct your own time class or use my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) whose class `PlainTime` supports the extended range.

Comment: @Meno According to [the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) `time` goes up to `24:00:00` inclusive.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the link, so we see that - in case of PostgreSQL - the standard jdbc interfaces like `java.sql.Time` cannot map the whole range. Consequence: Let's use simple number fields or similar for the mapping of whole range 00:00-24:00.

Answer (score 1):

"24:00:00" is "00:00:00" 
There is no difference, time goes in cycles so after "23:59:59" the default next value is "00:00:00". So i don't see a problem there.

If you insist on having 24:00:00 I suggest you check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106357/simpledateformat-that-allow-240000-and-000000-as-inputs)

Comment: Problem is in my tiny project I'm not considering seconds. Hence there's always a gap of 1 minute (00:00 - 23:59 =1). To solve this problem I want to set 00:00 as "24:00"

Comment: Im sorry i don't understand. There is always a gap of one minute every time. 23.58 ==> 23.59 also 1 minute gap. just like with all other times

Comment: 00:00 represent start time of next day, 23:59 represent last time possible for previous day. Hence 1 minute of previous day is lost here. okay let me make it clear. Assume a person has to get paid for two consecutive days from 18:00:00 to 03:00:00. for first day he will paid for 18:00:00 ==> 23:59:00 and for the next day 00:00:00 ==> 03:00:00. What happens here is the person is losing pay for 1 minute of previous day.

Comment: If you do not want lost that minute, use higher precision instead...what are you thinking of now? Or just directly use timestamp.

Comment: @Hearen I can't use seconds and also timestamp uses date to represent next day with "00:00:00" time for "24:00:00".

Comment: I do not agree with the statement `"24:00:00" is "00:00:00"`. The former is end of day, the latter start of day. 24:00 on day (X), is 00:00 on day (X+1).

Comment: There is a difference.
startTime = 10:00
endTime = 24:00 (00:00)
If you have loop like this
`for (LocalTime time = startTime; time.isBefore(endTime); time = time.plusMinutes(30))` it'll not work